# Editable PDF's using Google Apps Script

Tags: api, pdf, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a PDF which will have editable fields using Google Apps Script. I've not found any way to do it yet, so I feel like it is not possible. So, I want to know if it is possible to create a PDF with editable fields or not.

Comment: Any Luck? also interested...

Answer (score 3):

There are NO native [built-in](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services) or [advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) in Google Apps Script that support creating a fillable PDF.

However, you might be able to integrate an existing open-source Javascript PDF library/module into your GAS project. NPM(Node package manager) and Github are good places to start your search. You'll need to find a library that targets the browser and has few or no dependencies.

Ideally, you would copy & paste the Javascript library/module as is into your GAS project and use it right out the box. However, that's not always the case. Even with support for V8, GAS does NOT support every feature in Javascript. So you might have to spend some time making the code compatible with GAS - which may not be possible depending on the feature you need to emulate.

I think it can be done, but I suspect it will take some work.

---

**UPDATE**

This library looks promising:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib/v/1.6.0

[I've seen references to that library in some Google Apps Script dev forums](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/mzdbKLTMV0s/m/TAORdr2CAgAJ), so it might be possible to use it to build a fillable PDF.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I gave my client another way to do his project. I will try to solve it in my free time and get back to you if succeeded, it might be helpful to you in future.